# Monitor a mule process from another mule flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a process which reads a file and uploads it to a database. The flow goes as below.

1. File connector
2. Processing within a for-each loop (Update to database)

The problem with the above approach was that at any time when an exception occurs, the processing stops at that record and the rest of the records are not processed. As a work around, I have changed the flow as below:

1. File connector
2. For each - Within the for-each a flow-ref is placed to call a separate flow which does the processing.

The thing that I noticed is that, at the point of calling the new flow, separate threads are used for processing, due to which an exception does not cause all the records to fail. Now I am facing another difficulty, which is that after the processing completes, I need to initiate a report with the complete processing details (no of records processed, rejected, etc). Since all the records are processed asynchronously in different threads, I am not able to figure out when the processing is completed. Is there a way to monitor whether the processing is complete from another mule flow, so that I can generate the report when it is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at the point of calling the new flow, separate threads are used for processing

A `flow-ref` doesn't necessarily imply a new thread: you can tune the `processing-strategy` of the ref-ed flow to force synchronous processing.

With this, you'll be able to remain synchronous, have a custom expression strategy in the ref-ed flow and achieve your goal of not breaking processing when an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks David for your answer. I will try this and see whether it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me and sorry for the delayed response, I got a chance to work on this only today. Thanks!